# Crash in audioInpuStream - not clear to me what actually happened

Tags: ios, crittercism

I just got this crash log from Crittercism. Now I suspect that it might be caused by a 3rd party library for cloud-based speech which I'm using (iSpeech), but I really can't tell. All I do know is that my own code does not call any of the mentioned methods, nor does it have a MyAudioQueueInputCallback in it.

Clues?

SIGSEGV -[audioInputStream setCurrentBuffer:] (audioInputStream.m:15)

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib 0x31331f7a objc_retain + 9
1    libobjc.A.dylib 0x31332ead objc_setProperty_non_gc + 44
2    libobjc.A.dylib 0x3133a82f objc_setProperty + 18
3    TypOHD 0x000c6c15 -[audioInputStream setCurrentBuffer:] (audioInputStream.m:15)
4    TypOHD 0x000c60f5 -[audioInputStream pushData:final:] (audioInputStream.m:457)
5    TypOHD 0x000c531d -[audioInputStream handleInput:] (audioInputStream.m:89)
6    TypOHD 0x000c54c1 MyAudioQueueInputCallback (audioInputStream.m:122)
7    AudioToolbox 0x36277375 _ZN20ClientMessageHandler19InputBufferCompleteEjjRK15XAudioTimeStampjPK28AudioStreamPacketDescription + 192
8    AudioToolbox 0x36278f01 _ZN29AQClientCallbackMessageReader17DispatchCallbacksEPhjPvj + 344
9    AudioToolbox 0x3627717b AQCallbackReceiver_CallbackNotificationsAvailable + 370
10   AudioToolbox 0x36224ea1 _XCallbackNotificationsAvailable + 60
11   AudioToolbox 0x3621ace3 mshMIGPerform + 374
12   CoreFoundation 0x314be523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 38
13   CoreFoundation 0x314be4c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 140
14   CoreFoundation 0x314bd313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1370
15   CoreFoundation 0x314404a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
16   CoreFoundation 0x3144036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
17   AudioToolbox 0x36273b2f _ZN20GenericRunLoopThread5EntryEPv + 122
18   AudioToolbox 0x361faca3 _ZN9CAPThread5EntryEPS_ + 214
19   libsystem_c.dylib 0x33cb6735 _pthread_start + 320
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the iSpeech library. It's since been fixed, so get out there and upgrade your libraries devs!